# How to see all of log history on ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, users, log, date, clock

I have a problem in my fingerprint installed on Ubuntu. Date and time system in ubuntu can be edited by the user, so the user late to the office and change the date and time system on ubuntu.
Can I see log or information about the modified date and time system by user?

Thank You

Comment: Is the user a local admin with sudo rights? If not, they can not change the system time anyway. If they are, you can't prevent them from changing the time or from modifying any local logs. If you can't trust your employees enough to not trick on you and they need local admin rights, you have to run the time recording on a remote server, e.g. through a simple web app.

Comment: Hello Byte Commander,

They do not have local admin with sudo, but they can edit time and date system from the panel.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I forgot that the GUI allows you to change system time without root privileges by using a dbus command. My recommendation of putting the time registration on a remote server gets even more weight then.

Answer (score 0):

Take the below steps to  see log history on ubuntu :

open terminal >

sys3011@sys3011:~$ sudo nautilus

[sudo] password for sys3011:

after enter the password folder will open.

now go to this path  **/var/log**

here you can get all log files

[log files folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RekU0.png)

Comment: Hello Ganga,
Yes, I know your opinion, but in path /var/log nothing information about time and date modified.
Thank You